# Undefined reference существующей функции?

Tags: c++, кросс-компиляция

Цель - собрать код с использованием OpenCASCADE (OCE) c crosscompile под windows. Для этого использую mxe с пакетом oce.

Сборка mxe и всех зависимостей прошла без проблем. Простые примеры собираются и запускаются. Но возникла сложность при линковке OCE:

Пример кода

```
#include <TopoDS.hxx>
#include <BRepMesh_IncrementalMesh.hxx>

int main(){
  TopoDS_Shape shape;
  BRepMesh_IncrementalMesh(shape, 0.1);
  return 0;
}
```

Собираю:

```
/usr/src/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-g++ -o code ../tmp/code.cxx \\
-I /usr/src/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/include/oce \\
-L /usr/src/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/lib/ \\
-lTKMesh -lTKPrim -lTKTopAlgo -lTKGeomAlgo -lTKBRep -lTKGeomBase -lTKG3d -lTKG2d -lTKMath -lTKernel
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
/tmp/ccCSrdq9.o:code.cxx:(.text$_ZNK15BRepMesh_Vertex8HashCodeEi[_ZNK15BRepMesh_Vertex8HashCodeEi]+0x65): undefined reference to `__imp__Z8HashCodedi'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Искомая функция Z8HashCodedi находится в libTKernel.a:

```
nm /usr/src/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/lib/libTKernel.a | grep Z8HashCodedi
0000000000000000 t _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z8HashCodedi
0000000000000010 T _Z8HashCodedi  << Standard_Real.cxx.obj
                 U _Z8HashCodedi  << TColStd_MapRealHasher_0.cxx.obj
```

Вопрос первый - почему nm показывает две строчки с совпадением?

Вопрос второй - почему компилятор не находит функцию?

---

Упростил код сведя к вызову проблемной фукнции

```
#include <Standard_Integer.hxx>
#include <Standard_Real.hxx>

int main() {
    Standard_Real r = 1.e0;
    Standard_Integer i = 1;
    return HashCode(r,i);
}
```

И в команде сборки оставил только -lTKernel, результат всё тот же.

Comment: Две строчки кажется из-за того, что в одной единице трансляции символ `_Z8HashCodedi` не определен `U`, а в другой определен `T`. А когда происходит ругание на `__imp__`, то это может подразумевать, что происходит статическая линковка бибилотеки, для которой ожидается динамическая линковка.

Comment: Для чистоты эксперимента собрал всё в docker контейнере moric/gcc-opencascade-win-x64-test и получил тот же результат